# Ansible - Create new dict based on matching items in list

Tags: dictionary, ansible

There is a list:

```yaml
mylist: ['a_value', 'something_else']
```

There is a dict:

```yaml
my_dict:
  a_value:
    something: true
  bar:
    foo: false
  something_else:
    placeholder: true
```

There is an Ansible task to set a fact for a new dict.

```yaml
- name: "Create a new dict, when name(s) in the list match the key in the dict"
  set_fact:
    new_dict: "{{ new_dict | default({}) | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  loop: 
    - "{{ my_dict | dict2items }}"
    - "{{ my_list }}"
  when: my_list??? item
```

**Q:** How would I configure Ansible to create a new dict, when the name(s) match the key in the dict?

In this example, desired output:

```yaml
new_dict:
  a_value:
    something: true
  something_else:
    placeholder: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You complicated the task by adding `my_list` in the loop, creating yourself a list of list and making it more complex that it really was.

So, as a first step, you could corrected your logic and do:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    new_dict: "{{ new_dict | default({}) | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  loop: "{{ my_dict | dict2items }}"
  when: item.key in my_list
  vars:
    my_list: ['a_value', 'something_else']
    my_dict:
      a_value:
        something: true
      bar:
        foo: false
      something_else:
        placeholder: true

- debug:
    var: new_dict
```

Which gives:

```
TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'a_value', 'value': {'something': True}})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'bar', 'value': {'foo': False}}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'something_else', 'value': {'placeholder': True}})

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  new_dict:
    a_value:
      something: true
    something_else:
      placeholder: true
```

---

**This said**, there is a way shorter approach, using [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr).
So, with this one-liner:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: my_dict | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', my_list) | items2dict
  vars:
    my_list: ['a_value', 'something_else']
    my_dict:
      a_value:
        something: true
      bar:
        foo: false
      something_else:
        placeholder: true
```

We get:

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_dict | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', my_list) | items2dict:
    a_value:
      something: true
    something_else:
      placeholder: true
```

Comment: Beautiful solution

Answer (score 2):

[*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the values of the *mylist* items
from *my_dict*

```yaml
  _values: "{{ mylist|map('extract', my_dict) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _values:
  - something: true
  - placeholder: true
```

Then create *new_dict*

```yaml
  new_dict: "{{ dict(mylist|zip(_values)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  new_dict:
    a_value:
      something: true
    something_else:
      placeholder: true
```

Comment: Another neat solution, thanks for sharing.